# Microsoft office word 2013 sharing a document allowing only edit/add comments

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, file-sharing

I've been trying to share a document in Microsoft Office Word 2013(in fact office 365) but in a way that other users only can comment it(like google drive).

I've tried in "REVIEW" the option "Restrict Editing" in "Editing Restrictions" Selecting "Comments". But there are two problems:
- I can't add me to exceptions.(I checked everyone so I'm an exception but I would like to only add me)
- When the other user try to comment in Word online going to "COMMENTS" it's not possible to add a comment because "it's protected by IRM" so it asks to open it in Word.

So the question is: what are the steps that should be followed to share a document in a way that other users only can comment it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of 'Everyone' in the "Restrict Editing" box, have you tried "More Users" option. Using this, you can add exception only for you.

Comment: @vembutech I tried it but when I typed my e-mail or my windows user it says: "Some of the users you have entered could not be added to the list because their names could not be verified"

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who finds this thread a few years on, so far I've found out that this feature seems to be intended for domain users and may not be expecting Office 365 or other Microsoft account users, based on the answer from a member of TechNet community support:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f3a7f8de-1156-4b66-a1ce-e41369ed002d/restricted-editing-not-accepting-new-users?forum=word

I hope that someday this would be enabled to include this usage scenario but for now we might be stuck with either 'Everyone can edit' or 'Nobody can edit'.

My own solution for now is going to have to be creating a parallel document just for reviewers (yuk), collecting feedback and then editing the master document, but that is then going to mean importing the comments, resaving the review copy before sending it out again for any updates. This will be more work but is the best I can think of for now.